# Resizing the window in Capybara with rack_test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, rack-test

I'm using `rack_test` as my driver for Capybara and I'm trying to resize the window.

The best example I could find on this was [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/8999306#file-features-support-env-rb-L157), but the `resize` method does not seem to work for `rack_test`

```
> Capybara.current_driver
=> :rack_test

> page.driver.resize(200, 200)
NoMethodError: undefined method `resize' for #<Capybara::RackTest::Driver:0x007fe4eb83bc60>
from (pry):22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried various other combinations I've seen online with no luck. Is there an easier way to resize the browser window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rack_test driver has no concept of windows or page size.  It is strictly an HTML parser, does no layout and very minimal CSS processing (basically just inline display: none checking).  If you need window resizing you will need to switch to one of the real browser drivers.